# Why are the most recent comments hidden?

Tags: discussion, comments

When comments beneath questions and answers are displayed, only the first (earliest) five are shown by default, with the 'Show (n) more comments' link displaying the rest. It seems to me it would make more sense to show the most recent comments, first, with a link at the top of the list to reveal earlier comments, much as happens on Facebook.

Is there a reason why it has been coded this way? Does anyone else feel that it would be more useful to show the five most recent comments by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, the top five highest RATED comments are shown first, assuming any comments are rated (otherwise it is just shown in chronological order). As for showing comments first to last, its really showing comments "top down", so that as you read, you start reading from the beginning of the conversation (which comment chains frequently are).

This is unlike facebook, where comments are more often directly related to the post, and less frequently "conversational". Showing the most recent comments works well on facebook...I do not think it would work as well here on PhotoSE or StackExchange in general, given how comments are used.